# Sockets issue in Java

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I'm trying to write a proxy in java using sockets, I have tried several methods (the last one using URLconnection), but were not very good...
A member of this forum recommended me to use the CONNECT property of the sockets to avoid header issues, and I'm trying to achieve a solution...

This is the part of code where I think that I have the problem, I'm trying to connect to "www.google.es" and send back the information again to the browser but I'm not receiving anything (I'm not getting any error).

```
//create outputstream to send the web page to the client
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            Socket socket = new Socket();

            // connect to some address and send/receive data
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host).getHostAddress(), 80));
            socket.getOutputStream().write("GET http://www.google.es/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.es\r\n\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte result[] = new byte[1024];
            socket.getInputStream().read(result);
            socket.close();
            System.out.println(new String(result));
            out.write(result);
            out.flush();
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing things wrong in this code and I would be very grateful if somebody could help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Try searching for this sort of thing online. For instance, I found [this useful article](http://www.jtmelton.com/2007/11/27/a-simple-multi-threaded-java-http-proxy-server/) with my first search query.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your answer, but this article is implementing the proxy in the same way I did the last time, this way I'm getting issues with the fonts in some url's...

Comment: So why don't you just try to solve those problems? Writing it all over again won't magically make it better.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd element in a GET command is a *path,* not a URL. But as I think I told you elsewhere, a proxy just copy bytes; it shouldn't send anything of its own. The CONNECT command just means to open a connection. If you succeed, send back a 200 reponse and then just start copying bytes in both directions simultaneously (i.e. two threads).